# Android Studio: Is it possible to work with a Scrollview not in "fullscreen"?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I am currently developing an android app for my final project.
I am using Android Studio to build the app and at this point I need a Scrollview because I have multiple buttons used to send GET requests to a local server and I also have a TextView to display the reply from the server (all buttons use the same TextView to display the answer from the server because the app will only be sending one GET request at a time).

My problem is : I'd like to make a Scrollview with all the buttons so I can scroll up/down to press the button with the GET request I want but I'd like to get the TextView in the bottom of the screen but not inside the Scrollview (static position).
I don't really know if I am being precise in discribing what I need but I'll try it in a different way: I'd like to use a Scrollview with all the buttons (using 100% of device's screen width but not 100% of the device's screen height - 90% maybe) and have the TextView with the reply always static in the bottom of the screen (the 10% left).

All the buttons "TEST" are not functional yet but they will be soon and I need them (and probably some more buttons) and used them to make the Scrollview bigger than the device's screen so I could try to solve this problem.

Can anyone please help me solving this problem ?

Thank you very very much !!

Right now my **activity_menu.xml** has the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#3a3a3a"
    tools:context=".MenuActivity">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3a3a3a">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/on_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/on"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/off_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/off"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/on_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateandtime_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/dateandtime"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/off_button"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resultsready_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/results_ready"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateandtime_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste1_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resultsready_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste2_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teste1_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste3_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teste2_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste4_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teste3_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste5_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="@string/test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teste4_button" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/get_response"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/results"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#4eab4e"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/teste5_button" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: I think you can put a scrollview and textview inside a vertical linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code, I just made small changes to the text references which you can change.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_weight="1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/get_response"
    android:background="#3a3a3a"
    android:fillViewport="false">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#3a3a3a">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/on_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="on"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/off_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="off"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/on_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/dateandtime_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="dateandtime"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/off_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/resultsready_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="results_ready"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/dateandtime_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste1_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/resultsready_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste2_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teste1_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste3_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teste2_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste4_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teste3_button" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/teste5_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:background="#4eab4e"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="4dp"
            android:text="test"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#626262"
            android:textSize="24sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/teste4_button" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</ScrollView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/get_response"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.2"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:text="results"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textColor="#4eab4e"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Did you try this?